# API to retrieve network path for a volume on OSX

Tags: macos, diskarbitration

I'm looking for a native OSX API to do the same as this unix command:

```
df -P /Volumes/samples
Filesystem                          512-blocks       Used   Available Capacity  Mounted on
//doe@stor.foo.com/samples 17414365488 2684246752 14730118736    16%    /Volumes/samples
```

i.e. retrieve this path "//doe@stor.foo.com/samples" or something similar for a given volume. I tried Disakarbitration but fail to find a key in there that carries that network path (the local path is there).

Comment: What counts as a "native OSX API"?  Is the API used by df(1) not native enough?

Comment: Do you happen to know what API call is used by df?

Comment: Not offhand but I know how to google for "site:opensource.apple.com df": https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-188/df/df.c.auto.html